# How to handle JSON data using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, d3.js, hybrid-mobile-app

Currently I have a json file that populates information to my chart. An example of this chart can be found here: http://marmelab.com/ArchitectureTree/. I also have a panel to the right which is meant to display the information of one of the charts node's when clicked. However I don't know how to do this.

Say if I had in my json array:

```
{
  "name": "Blogs",
  "url": "blogs.my-media-website.com/*",
  "dependsOn": ["Wordpress MU"],
  "technos": ["PHP", "Wordpress"],
  "host": { "Amazon": ["?"] }
},
```

I would click on 'Blogs' in the chart and the 'url', 'dependsOn' etc would then be displayed in the panel. I'm sure this function uses AngularJS to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried, there are a wealth of articles and even angulars documentation on this is impressive..

Answer (score 0):

On click of Blogs call below function :

In your controller, try adding this function.

```
$scope.onClickOfBlogs = function(){
         $http.get('Your_JSON_file_Path_here').success(function(response){
                $scope.jsonObject= response;
            }).error(function() {
                console.log('error occured while getting JSON file');
            });
        };
```

in your Panel HTML : -

```
<div id ="info">
           <span>URL : {{jsonObject.url}} </span>
           <span>Name : {{jsonObject.name}} </span>
           <ul>
            Depends on :
          <li ng-repeat = "depends in jsonObject.dependsOn"> <!-- to iterate on array you need ng-repeat -->
               {{depends}}
         </li>
 </ul> 

</div>
```

you will get the data from json file into your html panel.Hope this helps.

**
**  :    http://plnkr.co/edit/dbJ0bhHhvASffJU9liY6?p=preview

Comment: Hi  I have created the Plunk.                                                http://plnkr.co/edit/dbJ0bhHhvASffJU9liY6?p=preview   Please have a look . and also please post what you have tried so far and what problem you got in last code.